# Count * query gets stuck at reducer 0% although the mapper completes

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a hive external table with 255 columns which has input data size of around 25 GB. This is a single node cluster set up with Hadoop-1.2.1 and hive-0.11.0.

I am able to create tables, databases etc... But when I try a count(*) query in hive, the mapper succeeds but the reducers never start. They are stuck at 0% forever.

The single node machine has a memory of 1TB. Any inputs here will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use beeline instead of hive, Hive is deprecated so some issues will not be resolved when it is getting deprecated.